# Problems with metamask/web3 connection

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I want to understand how front-end of smart contracts works.
I'm trying to run this code on my computer but metamask is constantly undefined.

Could you please explain why it happens in details.
Why it does not connect to metamask provider?

```
        <script>
            $(".sendButton").click(function(){
                let Web3 = require('web3');
                if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
                    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
                }
                else {
                    alert('You have to install MetaMask !');
                }
                const abi = some abi
                const contractAddress = "some contract";
                let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
                let myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);
                let functionData = myContractInstance.setMessage.getData($('#inputString').val());
                web3.eth.sendTransaction({
                        to:contractAddress,
                        from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
                        data: functionData,
                    },
                    function(error, response){
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hate to ask the question, but do you have MetaMask installed? Using the same computer and web browser, are other websites able to make use of MetaMask?

Comment: MetaMask works without problems on other websites
@smarx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're locally serving an HTML file, MetaMask will not be able to communicate with your DApp. A web server is required. From the [MetaMask Developer Docs](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md):

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

Also, please note the [MetaMask breaking change](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) which will no longer automatically inject `web3` into the browser. Instead users must grant the DApp access to their accounts via accepting a prompt dialog created by `window.ethereum.enable()`. See the below code for handling MetaMask in both modern DApp browsers as well as legacy DApp browsers.

```js
// Modern DApp Browsers
if (window.ethereum) {
   web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
   try { 
      window.ethereum.enable().then(function() {
          // User has allowed account access to DApp...
      });
   } catch(e) {
      // User has denied account access to DApp...
   }
}
// Legacy DApp Browsers
else if (window.web3) {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
}
// Non-DApp Browsers
else {
    alert('You have to install MetaMask !');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Omg man!! Thank you sooo sooo much :)))))))))

Comment: Now my whole dapp is working as expected, I love you man, really do <3